# Initializing / Building Autodesk Maya menus wihout using user interface

Tags: scripting, menu, initialization, menuitem, maya

I'm coding a function able to read the main window Maya menus and create a MasterList that contains all menus hierarchy, traversing everything all.

But the problem is.... menus are not loaded by Maya until user invoke it with the mouse or keyboard using the interface... so, if you don't open the menu, Maya doesn't internally loads it!.

This is easily understandable running this command Before and After click for the very first time after open Maya in the "File" menu (from Python tab):

```
cmds.menu("mainFileMenu", q=True, ia=True)
```

With "echo commands" (ScriptEditor > History > Echo all commands marked), its possible to observe how the first time you open a menu, some "custom" (undocumented, internal) commands are called:

```
buildFileMenu();#The very first time you click on "File" menu    
checkMainFileMenu;#The next times you click on "File" menu
buildEditMenu("MayaWindow|mainEditMenu");
ModObjectsMenu MayaWindow|mainModifyMenu;
editMenuUpdate("MayaWindow|mainEditMenu");
```

etc...

Considering my script will read every menus, and knowing in several Maya versions, menus change (get augmented / reordered / removed / managed)..., I can't hardcode this...

There is some way to force Maya to load/initialize all the Menus to be able to read it from scripting?. There is no documentation about that "build-menus" commands and them can change from one version to another as new features or new reorganization happens.

Any idea? Need some help!

Comment: As much as I know all the commands are available in the maya/scripts/startup directory. If you search for the corresponding enties, you should be able to see what's happening. But of course to get a complete list, it would be necessary to parse the mel files.

Comment: Is a chance!, I've been researching a bit, there is much more besides Maya main menu... but thanks!, an element more to play with in my head, hope soon the light bulb shine!.I've been trying to access to command executed by menu at clicking, but still no lucky